# How are fields (algebra) related to vector/scalar fields?

Tags: terminology

Is there a reason as to why they both have similar etymologies? If not, is there a big book of mathematical etymologies? Please include sources, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They have nothing to do with each other except insofar as "field" means "a bunch of stuff." You might be interested in consulting this list of [earliest known uses of some of the words of mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html).

In general you shouldn't take mathematical etymology too seriously. It's common for people to use the same name for unrelated things; see, for example, [this old MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7389/what-are-the-most-overloaded-words-in-mathematics).